# How can you pass a complex object into a kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a game I am building and the whole game logic is contained in a `Game()` class.  I would like to pass an object of this game into the kv file.  Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class Game():
    name = "Game Name"

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player


build = """
WindowManager:
    HomeScreen:


<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            text: "New Game"
            on_release:
                app.root.load_game("player")
                app.root.current = 'game'


<GameScreen>:
    name: 'game'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Label:
            text: root.game.name
"""


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class GameScreen(Screen):
    player = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, player, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.player = player
        self.game = Game(self.player)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def load_game(self, player):
        self.add_widget(GameScreen(player))


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(build)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().run()
```

This runs, but when I try to click the button to instantiate the game screen it throws an error saying that the GameScreen doesn't have a "game" property.  There isn't, as far as I'm aware, a `ClassProperty` property in Kivy, how would I pass in an object that's not a primitive type?

Comment: If I run your code in a Python 3.9 virtual environment on Windows 10 64-bit with kivy installed, with no command-line options, no errors are thrown. What environment are you trying to run in, and what are you passing your script on the command-line?

Comment: @Grismar I have just edited my question, it runs just fine until I click on the button.  After I click the button in "HomeScreen" which runs the `load_game` method, it then throws the error.  It is unable to see the game object, though it does have access to the `player` string object as that was setup with `StringProperty()`

Comment: "There isn't, as far as I'm aware, a `ClassProperty` property in Kivy". Well, what kinds of properties *are* there? When scrolling through the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html), just looking at the names of the `Property` subclasses, do you see anything that might be relevant?

Comment: Well I feel rather dumb, `ObjectProperty` is the answer, isn't it...  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an object as a property:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty # Import ObjectProperty


class GameScreen(Screen):
    player = StringProperty() 
    game = ObjectProperty(Game) #Add an object property
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Answer was right in front of me